# select particular key by name from HttpFileCollection

Tags: httpfilecollection

how to select particular item from HttpFileCollection Object

```
  HttpFileCollection uploads = default(HttpFileCollection);
        uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
```

I want to select some keys from uploads

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need

```
    if (context != null)
            {
                if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    var file0 = context.Request.Files[0];
 var file1 = context.Request.Files[1];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Actuall i have many items inside uploads and i want to select some not all from that